# Waiting for an object to be instantiated in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm having a hard time figuring out how best to do this. I have a model that instantiates a few collections in its initialize method. Immediately after instantiating that model, I need to get a model in one of those collections but at the time I try to get that model it seems to not be available so I end up getting 'undefined' instead. This is what I have:

```
var App = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.users = new Users();
    }
});
app = new App();
someUser = app.users.get("someuserID"); // -> undefined
```

But if I do:

```
var App = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.users = new Users();
    }
});
app = new App();
setTimeout(function(){
    someUser = app.users.get("someuserID"); // -> user instance
},3000);
```

I tried adding a `this.trigger("loaded")` to the App initialization method and then listening for that event but the event doesn't trigger. Like so:

```
var App = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.users = new Users();
        this.trigger("loaded");
    }
});
app = new App();
app.on("trigger",function(){ // -> never actually triggers
    someUser = app.users.get("someuserID");
});
```

Any ideas?

Note that the Users collection IS fetching the users correctly from a restful API.

Thank you,

Luis

Comment: I suspect triggering an event for an object from within its initialize method does not actually work because the object is not done initializing, right? So my question may be: is there a way to trigger an "initialized" event after initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the collection has completed the `.fetch`, it will fire a `reset` event, per the [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch). You haven't included your `Users` class here, but assuming it's just a Collection and not a wrapper for one, you'd do the following:

```
var App = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.users = new Users();
    }
});
app = new App();
app.users.on('reset',function() { var someUser = app.users.get("someuserID"); });
```

Comment: Arrrgggg!!! You beat me to it! Haha. I just saw an example of this. But thank you. You win!